# How to compile in Visual Studio 2010 for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to develop C/C++ on Windows using Visual Studio 2010 (not necessarily the MSVC Compiler) and get a binary that I can upload to a linux machine (and run it)?

On possibility I checked was to use MinGW or something similar to get windows binaries doing the same thing that linux binaries would do but I had problems to get all win-ports for all needed libraries (posix).

EDIT: I do not want to let the windows binary run on linux. I need a native linux binary as a result.

Comment: Yes, you can.  You just have to find (or write yourself) custom build tasks to call your cross-compiler.  Also, you have to find (or build yourself) a cross-compiler.  Neither of these steps are particularly easy to do yourself, but if you have the patience to do them, they are quite doable (I have done both; it took a couple of weeks, total).  If you're building software for Linux, though, it'd be a lot easier to compile it on Linux.

Comment: What features of the IDE would you expect to use, other than the editor and the ability to shell out and run `make`?

Comment: @James: What cross-compiler would you suggest?

Comment: @Greg: The IDE is not my decission :-|

Comment: You need to use wine (http://www.winehq.org/) for running windows applications in linux ( ie developed using vs ) , otherwise u can use the cross platform frameworks like QT (http://qt.nokia.com/products/)

Comment: I have a feeling you're not telling us the whole story. How can the target platform be up to you, but the IDE is not your choice? That makes no sense.

Comment: @Greg: We have a team mostly comfortable with Visual Studio. To change that the alternative has to be better.

Comment: @schoetbi:  You need to build one for your target.  The cross compiler should be built against the same C runtime and Standard Library that are in use on the target system.  I've used [crosstool](http://kegel.com/crosstool/) to target older versions of RHEL, and it works okay, though even with an automated script, you are likely in for _at least_ a few days of tweaking and rebuilding just to get a working cross compiler for a particular target. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: [In my opinion, you'd be far better off writing as much platform-neutral code as possible, and using a cross-platform build system like CMake to build on both platforms.]

Comment: @James: Agree here. My feeling now is that the team could use MSVC to develop and test the platform-neutral code and the rest could be compiled using a virtual machine with the proper build-tools.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to all of you!  My solution is summarized:

1. Platform-independent code is developed using Visual Studio
2. Final Build (for Linux) is performed using a Virtual Box running Debian or RHEL
3. IDE within the Virtual Box is Eclipse with the CDT plugin
4. Use CMake To generate the project files for both Visual Studio and Eclipse CMake

Comment: Hello. Probably, topic is old, but can i ask you to put more details about your solution, please? For example, what is "Platform-independent code is developed". Probably i have the same problem now as you 4 years ago. Hope technology change also did changed something in your workflow. I dream to use one codebase for different platforms.

Comment: What it means is basically that you need an OS-Abstraction Layer. You could use one existing one, or encapsulate each OS-call you need in a wrapper function. Maybe you look into [POCO C++](http://pocoproject.org/)

Answer (score 3):

I have some opinions on this, but it is hard to weigh in without more information.  Why is it that you want to develop in Visual Studio?  What type of application are you targeting?  Is there a level of code maturity that already exists?  Are there team experience issues influencing this decision?

My knee-jerk reaction is that it sounds like you want the benefits of the VS 2010 development environment in terms of developer productivity while developing an application to be used in a Linux environment.  If I were faced with that, I would probably be targeting portable C# using mono on a Linux-based constant integration server with short-term check-ins (once an hour or so should be fine) in order to weed out non-portable code.  However you specified C++, so that's probably not a perfect fit for you assuming that is a requirement.

With C++ as a hard requirement, and Visual Studio as a hard requirement, the plan you posted sounds like a good one.  In addition I would definitely want a constant integration server running on the target platform with short-term check-ins to prevent any significant code development of non-portable code.  TFS can handle this if you have MSDN licenses (and provides for tool integration in both Visual Studio and Eclipse).  There are plenty of other good options as well, but you seem to be drawn toward the Microsoft stack.

Comment: +1 for this. The thing is that we want to develop a realtime application (thats why C# is not an option). TFS is not needed since we use SVN/Jenkins with local git repos for each developer. Integration test is allways good. Jenkins can also fire up a virtual machine to test software on e.g.: the linux platform. Thanks.

Comment: Is your target platform Redhawk?  This is starting to sound like my day job.  When I say constant integration I mean have the devs do small changes and check in around once an hour (or more often) and have that check-in kick off an automated full build of the product, notifying the dev immediately if that build fails.  I'm not familiar with Jenkins, maybe that provides this capability.  Preferably each code mod is preceeded by a test case, but that is off-topic.

Comment: No, I do not know Redhawk. CI: That is exactly what Jenkins can do for you. http://jenkins-ci.org/

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think that you can cross-compile targetting Linux/x86 with a visual studio compiler.

<sup>(I don't know Windows, but I heard that Microsoft is not very friendly towards Linux and does not develop cross-compilers)</sup>

The easiest way for you to compile your code for Linux/x86 is to install a complete Linux distribution (on your laptop, or perhaps in a virtual machine).

You could perhaps compile (for Windows host) GCC and binutils to get a cross-compiler targetting Linux/x86 and running on Windows, but I won't recommend that to a newbie.

<sup>(If you have an entire team knowing only Windows, you need to spend resources to have the team learn Linux, and that is easier if each developer has a Linux system on his desktop. Of course learning take time, effort, and has some cost; and most of the efforts will be spent in learning programming under Linux, e.g. the Linux system calls and common APIs and libraries; so keeping Visual is not going to win much, and will cost you!)</sup>

Comment: As I said I do not need to use the MSVC. Is there a project that allrady managed to get such a cross-toolchain?

Comment: I don't use Windows, so I am not the best person to ask. However, I never heard of such a cross-toolchain widely distributed in packaged binary form for Windows. **I strongly advise you to install Linux** on your computer (you can install it on a separate disk partition -it will co-exist with Windows, and you'll choose at boot time which OS to boot-, or in a virtual machine).